# Replace a string between two strings with regex

Tags: regex, sed

I have the following regex:

`(\<parent\>(?s).*\<version\>).*(\<\/version\>(?s).*\<\/parent\>)`

Which should work on the following text:

```
<name>CTR</name>

<!-- Parent -->
<parent> 
    <groupId>cxxdsds</groupId>
    <artifactId>c222</artifactId>       
    <version>5.0.0-REPO</version>
</parent>

<scm>
```

I want to replace the string between <version> and <version>. But my sed does not work:
`sed -i 's/(\<parent\>(?s).*\<version\>).*(\<\/version\>(?s).*\<\/parent\>)/\1xxxxxxx\2/g' pom.xml`
Any ideas?

Comment: `sed` works on a single line only by default, `(?s)` isn't supported (see [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/119905/109046) for details), etc. I'd also suggest to use tools like `xmlstarlet` instead of `sed`

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, you could try following `sed` code for substitution.

```
sed 's/\(<version>\)[^<]*\(<.*\)/\1xxxxxxx\1/' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, using `sed`'s back reference capability to store `<version>` and `</version>` in 2 different capturing groups and then while performing substitution adding new value `xxxxxxx` between 2 capturing groups as per required output.

***2nd solution:*** Using `awk` in case you want to look for tag `<parent>` as per shown samples and you want to replace version only in it then try following.

```
awk '
/<parent>/ { found=1 }
/<version>/{
  line=$0
  next
}
/<\/parent>/ && found{
  if(line){
    sub(/>.*</,">xxxxxxx<",line)
  }
  print line ORS $0
  line=found=""
  next
}
1
' Input_file
```